# Removing duplicate strings from text file using RegEx

Tags: regex, string, duplicates

I would like to remove strings from a file that already existed in a line with less number suing RegEx(Note++).

Example -

```
123   = 45,
789 = 321,
123     =   951
```

Should result in -

```
123   = 45,
789 = 321,
     =   951
```

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, you can't match newlines with regular expressions in Notepad++, so I'm not sure this can be done (unless you used several steps, where you first combine all lines into a single line then perform the replacements).

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is a good example of how though RegEx is very powerful, it is not always the right tool for the job.  For instance, the following RegEx will probably do what you want (I don't have Notepad++ installed, but it works in my RegEx client)

```
Search: (\b\d+\b)(.+?)\1
Replace: \1\2 (or $1$2, depending on your setup)
```

This takes and instance of a number, searches until it finds another instance of it, then replaces the entire thing with itself minus the second instance.

However, aside from being pretty dirty, this type of thing would be much simpler using a quick script or even something like Excel.